# G1 - Can I Update to Newer Versions of Android?

Tags: updates, htc-dream

I'm considering getting a G1 from T-Mobile (in the US), and am wondering, can I can update to new versions of Android as they come out, even ones targeted towards newer Android phones? For example, would I be able to update my G1 to Android 2.0 when it is available?

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7150/g1-misbehaving-can-i-should-i-reinstall-donut/7152

Comment: Oh wow, this is a really old question, October 29 '09?

Comment: @Bryan: Back when there was only SO, SF, and SU.

Comment: @BryanDenny: Oh wow. I completely forgot that I asked this question :)

Answer (score 3):

[Possibly not according to Engadget:](http://www.engadget.com/2009/08/17/t-mobile-g1-wont-see-any-android-updates-beyond-1-5/)

> Pioneering T-Mobile G1 owners have
>   been enjoying the spoils of Android
>   1.5 (or Cupcake, as it's known 'round these parts) for months now, but it
>   looks as if that very treat will be
>   the last taste of confectionery
>   goodness that the smartphone gets.
>   According to Android software engineer
>   Dave Sparks, a time is soon coming
>   when devs "wont be able to fit the
>   latest [Android] release on the G1's
>   internal flash," and yet another
>   engineer has chimed in via Twitter to
>   say that he "can't promise" that any
>   update after 1.5 will fit. **For
>   whatever reason, HTC gifted the G1
>   with an incredibly meager amount of
>   internal flash, and considering that
>   no Android phone will support app
>   storage / loading from a microSD card,
>   there's no way to free up room for
>   Donut, Eclair or Flan**. You've been a
>   real champ, G1, but without 2.0+, we
>   just can't give you the love and
>   devotion you truly need. Go on, call
>   us fickle -- we deserve it.

However, I'm sure there will be a hacked release available, since [Droiddog reports video's showing Android 2.0 running on a G1.](http://www.droiddog.com/android-blog/2009/10/android-2-0-eclair-running-on-g1s/) So keep an eye out [for the guys over at XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=448) for getting a cooked ROM.

Most likely it will be possible, but they probably won't support it...

Comment: Donut did make it to the G1 via an OTA update since that post.  Time will tell if Eclair will.

Comment: I think that when they made this statement they didn't know for sure what version number Donut was going to get (turned out it was 1.6). Still like Droiddog says: it works, so you could install it yourself

Comment: Froyo has definitely made it to the Magic, which has almost the same internals as the Dream/G1. There have been unofficial ports of the Magic Froyo back to the Dream, see the "When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?" post http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo

Answer (score 2):

If it's a T-mobile release, they will download it to your phone.  I've received two upgrades since getting my phone in April.  I believe Android is a platform on top of which the phone carriers build their specific release.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the process, though I'm not 100% they will supply it

Answer (score 2):

The last official version for the G1 was Android 1.6.

If you want Android 2.0+, you must root the device and install a custom rom such as CyanogenMod. [Full instructions and other information can be found here.](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=HTC_Dream)  Note that the G1 is no longer supported after CM6 (Android 2.2), but there may be other custom roms available to obtain Gingerbread (Android 2.3).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not without rooting it and modding it. My G1 came with 1.6-Donut installed. Find recommendations on suitable ROMs at [G1 Misbehaving -- can I (should I?) reinstall donut?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7150/g1-misbehaving-can-i-should-i-reinstall-donut/7152#7152)